# install serf 1.3.8 with error: libserf-1.so: undefined reference

Tags: svn

I'm trying to install serf on SUSE, which needed by svn-1.9.3, but encounter some problems.

Runtime Environment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1 (x86_64)

I have installed Apr-Util-1.5.4, OpenSSL-1.0.2g. and follow this web:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.9/basicnet/serf.html

try:

scons APR=/usr/local/apr-1.5.2 APU=/usr/local/apr-util-1.5.4 OPENSSL=/home/aisp/bak/serf-1.3.8-wRelate/openssl-1.0.2g PREFIX=/usr/local/serf-1.3.8

and then 
scons-2.4.1 check
Error occured:

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test/serf_get.o -c -std=c89 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wall -g -O2 -pthread -DNDEBUG -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/usr/local/apr-1.5.2/include/apr-1 -I/usr/local/apr-util-1.5.4/include/apr-1 -I/home/aisp/bak/serf-1.3.8-wRelate/openssl-1.0.2g/include test/serf_get.c
test/serf_get.c: In function 'main':
test/serf_get.c:418:21: warning: variable 'request' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     serf_request_t *request;
                     ^
gcc -o test/serf_get -pthread -Wl,-rpath=/home/aisp/bak/serf-1.3.8-wRelate/serf-1.3.8 test/serf_get.o -L. -L/usr/local/apr-1.5.2/lib -L/usr/local/apr-util-1.5.4/lib -L/home/aisp/bak/serf-1.3.8-wRelate/openssl-1.0.2g/lib -lserf-1 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lapr-1 -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -laprutil-1 -lexpat
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `sk_pop_free'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `sk_value'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_num_locks'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `SSLv23_client_method'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`sk_num'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'
./libserf-1.so: undefined reference to`SSLeay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [test/serf_get] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

I could not find the answer anywhere. What should I do?